# ionic2 angular2 How can I set value of an input component to an element in storage

Tags: angular, input, ionic2, local-storage

I am new to ionic2 angular2, I have an app that requests address from users, I want to make sure that if a user has entered the address before and he want to use the app to make another request, the address submitted in the first request is automatically set into the input component, how do I go about it?

this is my service address

```
<div id="serviceAddress" *ngIf = "showServiceAddress">
<h4>  Service address</h4>
<ion-list>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Addreess</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name= "address" #address [(ngModel)]="addValue"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Landmark</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="landmark" #landmark></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Contact</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="contact" #contact></ion-input>
  </ion-item>


    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, h:mm A" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>

    </ion-item>


    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Time</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm A" pickerFormat="h mm A" [(ngModel)]="event.timeStarts" name="protime" #protime></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>



<button ion-button icon-right float-right (click)=goToSubscriptionPage()>
 Next
  <ion-icon name="arrow-round-forward"></ion-icon>
</button>

</div>
```

and this is my ts file

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SubscriptionPage } from '../subscription/subscription';
import { RequestPage } from '../request/request';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-electrical',
  templateUrl: 'serviceaddress.html'
})
export class ServiceaddressPage {

@ViewChild("address") address;
@ViewChild("landmark") landmark;
@ViewChild("contact") contact;

data:string;
addValue:any;

 public event = {
    month: '2017-09-19',
    timeStarts: '07:43',
    timeEnds: '2040-09-20'
}

 FQNewBuilding(){
 this.storage.get('address').then((value) => {
var addressTxt = value
console.log(addressTxt)
});

 this.storage.get('landmark').then((value) => {
 var landmarkTxt = value
 console.log(landmarkTxt)
});
 this.storage.get('contact').then((value) => {
  var contactTxt = value
  console.log(contactTxt)
});

this.storage.get('address').then((value) => {
var addressTxt = value 

this.addValue = addressTxt});

 }
```

please note that I have remove some part of the code that are not relevant to the question.

the issue is the local storage value of address is not set to addValue of my input ngModel

Comment: where are you setting in the storage?

Comment: dont you need to inject storage in your component's constructor's first?

Comment: Note that the storage itself is working, it is injected fine, the console.log is working, all i need is to be able to assigned it to the input value of the address field

Comment: I am trying to understand this - do you require the address to be stored (so if a user closes the app, it'll retain the address), or can you not pass the address to the Input page/component so you don't even have to rely on storage. That'll be easier... I'll make a recommendation so you can utilise the Form (@angular/forms) API which will do what you require.

Comment: why not use ngModel?